# Replacing item by id of object in Flutter from listview.builder

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-scrollbar

I am using the scrollable_positioned_list as seen here https://pub.dev/packages/scrollable_positioned_list to scroll to a specific item when a notification occurs.

By default the builder take the index to identify which index to go to, but for my purpose i need to take the ID as identifier.

Is it possible to replace this :

```
itemScrollController.scrollTo(
          index: 3,
          duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500),
          curve: Curves.easeInOut,
        );
```

but to get to the ID of the object in the list ?

Comment: do you want to identify item by id?

Comment: The item in my list, yes !  So i can scroll to the item

Comment: code you please include your model class?

Comment: This is not relevant to the model but the screen... the model could be anything since I am interested by the ID of an object. 
I already have the ID (primary key of my object) I want to use it to scroll to this item in my list

Comment: Is this ID, part of that item class model? for example item(id:1, name:something...)

Comment: Yes, the list is using a future from which I have a model with ID for each object

Comment: @Mcflan_g you can set index,via filtering your ID from your object list,
attach your model class for code

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
    var items = list.where((element) => element.id == 'ID');
    if (items != null && items.isNotEmpty) {
      var index = list.indexOf(items.first);
      itemScrollController.scrollTo(
          index: 3,
          duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500),
          curve: Curves.easeInOut,
        );
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var item = itemList .where((ele) => ele.id == 'YOUR_ID');
    if (item != null && item.isNotEmpty) {
      var itemIndex = list.indexOf(item.first);
      itemScrollController.scrollTo(
          index: itemIndex ,
          duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500),
          curve: Curves.easeInOut,
        );
    }
```